# Regular expression greedy issue

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a string using Python and extract 2 tokens separated by `:` (a colon), that may be enclosed in single quotes, double quotes, or no quotes.

Sample cases working:

```
# <input string> -> <tuple that should return> 

1) abc:def -> (abc, def)
2) abc:"def" -> (abc, def)
3) "abc":def -> (abc, def)
4) "abc":"def" -> (abc, def)
5) "a:bc":abc -> (a:bc, abc)
```

Sample cases not working:

```
# <input string> -> <tuple that should return> 

6) abc:"a:bc" -> (abc, a:bc)
7) "abcdef" -> (abcdef,)
```

The regular expression used was:

```
>>> import re
>>> rex = re.compile(r"(?P<fquote>[\'\"]?)"
                     r"(?P<user>.+)"
                     r"(?P=fquote)"
                     r"(?:\:"
                     r"(?P<squote>[\'\"]?)"
                     r"(?P<pass>.+)"
                     r"(?P=squote))")
```

I've 2 problems, first the samples cases 6) and 7) are not working, and second after `rex.match` I want all groups matched but not the `fquote` and `squote` ones. What I mean is right now `rex.match("'abc':'def').groups()` returns `("'", "abc", "'", "def")`, and I just want `("abc", "def")`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `csv` module instead of a regex here:

```
inputs = [
    'abc:def', 'abc:"def"', '"abc":def', '"abc":"def"', '"a:bc":abc', #working
    'abc:"a:bc"', 'abcdef' # not working

]

import csv
for idx, el in enumerate(inputs, start=1):
    print idx, tuple(next(csv.reader([el], delimiter=':')))
```

Which gives you:

```
1 ('abc', 'def')
2 ('abc', 'def')
3 ('abc', 'def')
4 ('abc', 'def')
5 ('a:bc', 'abc')
6 ('abc', 'a:bc')
7 ('abcdef',)
```

Comment: It does not work with single and double quotes mixed. Example: s = '\'abc\':"a:bc"'

Comment: @user1595496 Ahh - didn't spot in your regex you were looking for either/or... Just at your example data ;)

Comment: I only want a regular expression and not using external module, but thanks anyway.

Comment: How is `csv` any more of an external module than `re`?  Anyway, regular expression addiction is hard to cure, I guess. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(string):
    rex = re.compile(r"(?P<fquote>[\'\"]?)"
                     r"(?P<user>.+?)"
                     r"(?:(?P=fquote))"
                     r"(?:\:"
                     r"(?P<squote>[\'\"]?)"
                     r"(?P<pass>.+)"
                     r"(?P=squote))"
                     r"|(?P<sfquote>[\'\"]?)"
                     r"(?P<suser>.+)"
                     r"(?:(?P=sfquote))")
    match = rex.match(string)
    suser_match = match.group("suser")
    return (suser_match,) if suser_match else (match.group("user"), match.group("pass"))
```

This does the job, but I strongly discourage it. Regular expressions should be kept as simple as possible, because this kind of solutions are difficult to understand, and therefore difficult to maintain. You might need a context-free grammar, which in my opinion fits better with the type of patterns you give as examples (Specially for the `"abcdef"` string, which requires a separate group).

Your second problem is symbolic groups are captured even if you put them inside `(?:...)`. That is why I think it is easier to retrieve them, and then create the tuple with the matched symbolic groups.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to retrieve all of the groups?  Just take the ones you're interested in and ignore the rest.  Here's an example:

```
rex = re.compile(
    r"""^(?:
      (?P<fquote>['"])
      (?P<user1>(?:(?!(?P=fquote)).)+)
      (?P=fquote)
      |
      (?P<user2>[^:"'\s]+)
    )
    (?:
      :
      (?:
        (?P<squote>['"])
        (?P<pass1>(?:(?!(?P=squote)).)+)
        (?P=squote)
        |
        (?P<pass2>[^:"'\s]+)
      )
    )?
    $""", 
    re.VERBOSE)

result = rex.sub(r"\g<user1>\g<user2> : \g<pass1>\g<pass2>", subject)
```

Additional notes:

- Splitting it up to handle the quoted and unquoted fields separately makes the job much, much easier.  You know one of each pair of groups will always be empty, so it's safe to concatenate them.
- `(?:(?!(?P=fquote)).)+` consumes one character at a time, but only after it confirms that the character is not the same as the opening quote.  You don't have to worry about it overrunning the closing quote, like `.+` would.  (You really should have been using a reluctant `.+?` there, but this is way is even better.)